# Unusual behaviour resulting from JQuery bind( )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attaching an event to a dynamically created `anchor` tag using `jQuery` however I'm getting an unusual effect which I will explain now.

Firstly, this is my `jquery`

```
$('#compresult').bind('click', 'a.con_add', function(e){
            console.log(e);
            $companyName = $('#comp_staff option:selected').text();
            $companyId = $('#comp_staff option:selected').val();
            $type = 'company';
            //Display Name of the Company
            $('#item_name').html(" - " + $companyName);
            //Update Hidden Fields of Form
            $('#comp_name').val($companyName);
            $('#comp_id').val($companyId);
            $('#type').val('contact');
            //Make AJAX request to PHP file which will generate the Tags for the Object
            $('#active_tags').load('pages/ajax/get_tags.php', {'name': $companyName, 'id': $companyId, 'type': $type},function(response, status, xhr){});
        });
```

`a.con_add` is the class of an anchor tag that does not exist when the page first loads, this is the `html` for that tag:

```
 <select style="width:300px" name="comp_staff" id="comp_staff">
           <option value="0">Select Contact...</option>
           <option value="25280">Person1</option>
           <option value="25274">Person2</option>
           <option value="162961">Person3</option>
           <option value="25275">Person4</option>
           <option value="139848">Person5</option>
           <option value="25279">Person6</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" class="con_add">Add Tag</a>
```

The strange behaviour is that the `click` event is triggered when I change the value of this select menu as opposed to clicking on the anchor tag. My guess is that the event is being `bind` to the entire div that the select menu is contained within?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `on` instead of `bind`? `on` is the preferred method of attaching events to elements sine jQuery 1.7. I can only assume that bind has not been updated and this is possibly the symptom of a regression.

Comment: can you show us where $('#compresult') is located?

Comment: Your syntax for .bind is incorrect. (or, more precisely, your use of it doesn't do what you think it does. `a.con_add` is being used as event data, not an element selector.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `.bind()`, but that does, as you theorized, bind the click event to the entire container. Just change that `.bind` to `.on` and your event delegation should work.

Comment: note that using .on will also bind the click event to the entire container. It will however only call the handler if the event target matches the selector.

Comment: ↑↑↑ Ya, just by filtering target element or any ancestors for bubbling events regarding selector passed

Comment: Yes, but I think OP's got the syntax correct so that it should delegate to a.con_add.

Comment: @BarryT.Smith your answer is correct, Kevin was just making things more clear